# Apache Shiro get subject method and Netty context

Tags: multithreading, netty, shiro

Shiro documentation says,

**"Shiro acquires Subject data based on the currently executing Thread via its own framework integration code, and this is the preferred way to use Shiro"**

If Shiro is getting subject from currently executing thread and Netty handles more than 1 requests using 1 thread. So, how get subject method will return subject information for a given request? And if Shiro is not handling this situation, do I need to add extra mechanism to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how netty works, but if you can configure it using Filters, shiro will make sure the threadlocal info is cleaned at the end of a request.

If you cannot use filters, you can probably hook in your own handling of putting/remove the subject on/from the thread.

Shiro uses the class ThreadContext for this: 
http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/util/ThreadContext.html

The methods ThreadContext.bind(securityManager) and ThreadContext.bind(subject) are the key methods. When a thread is done, call ThreadCOntext.remove().

If you check out this page, you'll see the thread stuff in action during a unit test: http://shiro.apache.org/testing.html